# Not able to align fragment to parent activity without removing navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am in the process of writing an android version of a iOS app I have helped create.

I am using a template navigation menu which puts a bar at the top and a menu at the side when dragged out or a button is pressed. This works fine, however the fragment comes with margins which leaves blank spaces between the bar and the layout.

I have tried removing the margins, but they then prevent the menu at the top from showing.

I am not sure which code snipped to include, so I have included the `home.xml` (fragment) `activity_main.xml` and the java files associated.

`home.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvNo"
    android:layout_gravity="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- The ActionBar -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </include>
</FrameLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

</uk.co.mrgyro.cropcirclelocatorandroid.FragmentNavigationDrawer>
```

`Home.java`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import uk.co.mrgyro.cropcirclelocatorandroid.R;

public class Home extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

    return rootView;
  }
}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package uk.co.mrgyro.cropcirclelocatorandroid;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private FragmentNavigationDrawer dlDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set a ToolBar to replace the ActionBar.
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Find our drawer view
    dlDrawer = (FragmentNavigationDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    // Setup drawer view
    dlDrawer.setupDrawerConfiguration((ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDrawer), toolbar,
            R.layout.drawer_nav_item, R.id.flContent);
    // Add nav items
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("First", R.drawable.ic_one, "First Fragment", Home.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Second", R.drawable.ic_two, "Second Fragment", SecondFragment.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Third", R.drawable.ic_three, "Third Fragment", ThirdFragment.class);
    // Select default
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        dlDrawer.selectDrawerItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    if (dlDrawer.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Uncomment to hide menu items
        // menu.findItem(R.id.mi_test).setVisible(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Uncomment to inflate menu items to Action Bar
    // inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (dlDrawer.getDrawerToggle().onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    dlDrawer.getDrawerToggle().syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    dlDrawer.getDrawerToggle().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

This is how it looks with the margins added
[image: Before]

This is how it looks with both margins in home.xml set to 0

[image: After]

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
</resources>
```

The appearance I would like is like the first image, except with no blank space.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show your snap shot how it looks and which type you want?

Comment: Hello Piyush, I have added two comparative images for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand very well your activities design and your layouts. If you need a navigation drawer and an action bar, I would just create one activity which extends `ActionBarActivity`and the navigation drawer written in the main xml. then in the content side of the navigation drawer place your activity content. In the code retrieve the action bar and the drawer and customize them as you want. You wont probably have those issues with margins etc and would be much more clean.

Comment: I will have a look into adapting that to what I need. I went for this approach from a tutorial to begin with as I could not find out how to add icons to the navigation drawer.

Comment: Android tutorials are pretty straightforward https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: They are good for explaining the concepts, however explaining how to actually put them in to practice they lack. I've got a second project open looking through at the moment to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
```

from your `Home` layout, and

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

from your activity layout.

Comment: Hello m vai, I have unfortunately tried this, it results in the second screenshot which shows the actionbar disappearing.

Comment: Fair dues for the quick responses, unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: Please post your styles.xml.

Comment: I have added it to the original post at the bottom for you.

Comment: Are you inflating the fragments into `android.R.id.content`?